# How do I write a function that maps a variable to a set?

Tags: functions, graph-theory, notation

I have a function $\Gamma$ that maps elements from $N$ to a (possibly empty) subset of $N$. The number of elements in the resulting subset depends on which element of $N$ we are dealing with, i.e. $\vert \Gamma(n) \vert$ depends on $n$.  How do I properly notate this in the $\Gamma : N \rightarrow \dots$ style?

I'm writing out some notes on implicitly defined digraphs: my domain is the set of nodes in the graph, and the function is the successor (or child) function that returns the set of direct children of a given node.

Comment: Gamma : N to P(N), where P(N) is the power set of N.

Comment: Might possibly use, $\Gamma : N \to \mathcal{P}(N)$, I think.

Comment: I also know the notation $\Gamma \colon N \rightrightarrows N$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$
\Gamma: N \rightarrow \mathcal{P}(N)
$$

where $\mathcal{P}(N)$ represents the [power set](https://www.mathsisfun.com/definitions/power-set.html) of function's domain.